# How to change color of the scrollbar in SynMemo with VCL styles

Tags: delphi, scrollbar, vcl-styles, synedit

there. I changed style of standard objects with VCl-theme.

I use Color, Font and Gutter properties to change style of SynMemo. But I don't know, how change style of ScrollBar of SynEdit( apply vcl-theme ). Who can help me ?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To add styling support for the `TSynEdit` you must register a style hook for such control. Try using the `TScrollingStyleHook` style hook.

Like so

```
TStyleManager.Engine.RegisterStyleHook(TCustomSynEdit, TScrollingStyleHook);
```

[image]